# CakePHP 3 ORM - Sorting based on two columns in two different related tables

Tags: sql, cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.0

Currently I'm trying to implement timeline functionality which requires to sort the created column in two related tables and update the parent table (in my case pictures) accordingly.

More specific, I have a pictures table which has many comments. I want to sort the pictures based on the most recent timestamp in the created column of both the comments and pictures table.

I have the following query which retrieves the necessary data but it isn't ordered properly:

```
public function getPicturesAndCommentsOfUser($userId){
    return $this->find()
        ->contain([
            'Comments' => function ($q){
                return $q
                    ->contain(['Users' => function ($q) {
                        return $q->select($this->select);
                    }])
                    ->order(['Comments.created' => 'ASC']);
            },
            'Users' => function ($q) {
                return $q->select($this->select);
            },
            'Albums'
        ])
        ->matching('Albums.Users', function ($q) use ($userId) {
            return $q
                ->where(['Users.id' => $userId]);
        });
}
```

My question is how to combine both the ordering of Pictures.created and Comments.created. I already tried to call the order function in both ->contain(['Comments']) and in the most outer part of the chain after the last matching call. I can't seem to figure out how to relate the two tables to each other so that I can sort on both of them.

Moreover, I read in other sources ([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335568/how-to-merge-unrelated-tables-but-sort-on-a-common-column-type)) that I could use an union statement but all the information I can find about that option is that it will work on unrelated tables, not related.

Anyone can give me some directions on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all your purpose should be clear. Which ordering has priority for you? `Pictures.created` or `Comments.created`? You can not sort the results based on both. When you do something like this:

```
$this->Comments->find()->order(['Pictures.created' => 'ASC'])->
    order(['Comments.created' => 'ASC']);
```

The ordering is only guaranteed for `Comments.created`. If two comments had equal times then they are ordered by `Pictures.created`.

There's another thing to be considered. Build the query on the object that is more populated. If each `Picture HasMany Comments` try to build your query on `Comments`. I don't have any idea how the results get sorted when you are building the query on `Pictures`. Because the retrieved records are sorted not by `Pictures.id` but when the result is translated to object models, Comments are nested in Pictures and previous orderings get disposed.

And at last don't make things complicated. Using php logic in queries doesn't improve the performance, otherwise it decreases your code readability. So if you are about to perform php logic first retrieve all data then process it using several simple `foreach`es.

Comment: I can't build my query on Comments since the overloading of the standard functionality of the plugin (Crud v4) that I use, only allows my to replace a query with something that starts in Pictures (I map the standard index method). I solved it now by retrieving every relevant picture sorted with the most recent comment as the first comment in the picture. After that I use a handcrafted sorting algorithm that gives me the proper result. Ugly, but it works.